# Is this phrase correct "but slightly they succeed"?

Tags: phrases

there is this phrase is correct:

```
They try so hard but slightly they succeed.
```

To describe this meaning:
Someone try so hard but fails.

## update:

For [mjsqu](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/68029/mjsqu)
Actually that's the definition that I intended but failed to communicate, to be more clear here's the phrase that I'm trying to use:

> Four major product exists in the market in the time of writing this report the four of them tried to remove the constraint that the others presents but slightly they succeed.

So those Four products removed some constraints that other presented but either they presented new ones or didn't removed enough constraint to be considered a valuable change.

Comment: No, this does not fit the definition you are intending exactly. It implies they tried and only succeeded partially.

Comment: Check updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the four of them tried to remove the constraints that the others present but they only partially succeeded

Answer (score -1):

It may not be wrong, but the word order is unconventional.

> They try so hard but [they] succeed only slightly.

would be a more normal phrasing.  You could even leave out the second 'they'

EDIT: mjsqu is correct, this does say that they did succeed some, as the original phrase did.

Comment: '... succeed slightly' sounds strange to my ears, probably along the lines of 'They won the competition slightly'. ' ... achieve only a bare modicum of success' sounds somewhat better. '... achieve so little' may be best.

Comment: Part of the problem here is that the original action to which "succeed" refers ("remove") is not one that "slightly" is good at modifying.

Comment: I agree with Edwin. It does sound unusual, but now that I think about it,  it sounds almost like a Whitman-esque imagery of words. "They tried so hard but slightly succeeded:" i.e., their attempt was effulsive but their success, in contrast, was meager.